# How can I enable cell protection rules on Web Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive, protected

I'm using the Office 365 app of Microsoft Excel and I'm trying to protect the sheet while enabling a few cells to edit.

While it works if I open the file in the app, the protection no longer works if a web version of the file has been opened. I have shared this file on OneDrive where I'm accessing it for the web version.

I've read that there are some formulae or rules that don't work with the web version but I've seen this work for some sheets.

Does anyone know of a solution or any dependencies that I might be overlooking here?

Comment: Which cell protection rules do you mean? If I lock cells via Excel desktop client, cells could also be locked on Excel for web.

Comment: I'm trying to lock cells using the "Protect Sheet" option. When I share the same file, I see that the protected cells can still be edited from the web version.